# POST method is not working in Codeigniter v4

Tags: codeigniter, post

I'm using form_open() for open form but form method is always showing get.

`echo $this->request->getMethod()` showing always get.

generated HTML is:

```
<form action="http://darkadmin.com/admin" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="45435e3abd2d067883dacd6f62280fa7" />
    <label for="fname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

View:

```
<?php if(isset($validation)) { ?>
<?php echo $validation->listErrors(); ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo form_open(current_url().'admin'); ?>
<label for="fname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
<label for="lname">Last name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Login extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct(){
        helper(['form', 'url']);
        
    }
    
    public function index()
    {   

        $rules = [
            'fname' => 'required',
            'lname' => 'required'
        ];

        echo $this->request->getMethod();
        if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post' && $this->validate($rules)){
            echo 'Success';
        } else {
            $this->data['validation'] = $this->validator;
        }
        return view($this->data['config']->theme.'login_view',$this->data);
        

        
    }
}
```

**How can I solve this problem? Please help me**

Comment: Do you have an Admin controller? In the form rhe action="http://darkadmin.com/admin points to admin controller right?

Comment: add `helper('form');` before `form_open();`

Comment: @J2112O Actually no. I have a sub directory named admin under app and public. Public and admin are separate MVC but system directory is same. Login controller in app/admin is base controller defined in route. Config file of public and admin are also separate.

Comment: #Vicky already used that.

Comment: @ParagDhali .Ok thanks for clarifying. I'm not sure I understand the whole project structure at this time.